# K-nearest neighbor model: stuck on a feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I am running a KNN model on a dataframe, attempting to predict a certain feature. I am trying to see if I can, depending on what row is be iterated, see if the particular "neighbors" that are found can possess a particular boolean value that I define.

For instance, let's say I wanted to iterate over a dataframe of authors, and I wanted to predict the value of their books based on the number of pages and chapters in the book. However, in my example, I only want to compare authors of the same AGE, and come up with the prediction based on authors with that same age.  I'm assuming that somewhere in the code I'd need to place a boolean value, I'm just not sure where?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

features = ['chapters','pages']
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=16, algorithm='brute')
knn.fit(train[features], train['value'])
predictions = knn.predict(test[features])
```

Here is the dataframe "test":

```
author   age   pages   chapters    value

green     34     324     10          9
white     21     432     24          6
smith     59     567     43          3
berg      34     229     8           11
carter    34     213     10          9
bing      21     501     34          15
moon      59     132     7           7
```

So, I'd want to find all of the KNN for author green but only those who are the same age, 34, as he is. And when it gets to author white, only find the KNN with the same age of 21. In other words, I need to have the age off the KNN == the age of the author it is predicting.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I could not find the feature that you need in the Sklearn model documentation.
You can use something as:

```
df.loc[df['age'] == 34]
```

or

```
df_agerange1 = df.loc[df['age'].between(25, 34)]
```

to train multiple models based on age range (store them in a dict for example) and use the right one for prediction depending on the age of the test example.

```
for i, d in test.iterrows():
    age = d['age']
    models[age].predict(d[features])
```

I know this is both computationally expensive and not so clean, but it could work.

Another approach for you could be to implement your own version of KNN from scratch and add this age constraint in the prediction function.

Furthermore, if you want the age to matter, but you are not so strict about it (because KNN weights each feature equally), you can just add age as a feature in training your model.

Comment: This hasn't quite worked but thank you for answering.  I'll try diving into the implementing the KNN from scratch -